Delphi TJson сериализует пустой массив как null
Метод TJson.ObjectToJsonString из стандартной библиотеки пустые массивы в объектах сериализует как null, например:
TTest = class
public
  my_array: array of integer;
end;

Сериализуется в:
{
  "my_array": null
}

хотя должно быть, видимо:
{
  "my_array": []
}

К тому же игнорируется опция joIgnoreEmptyArrays.
Это очень похоже на ошибку Delphi 10.1 Berlin, так как в следующих версиях это поведение вроде бы исправили.
Но можно ли что-то сделать в версии Berlin, чтобы не менять всю среду ради исправления такой ошибки?

Найти исходники другой версии, где исправили, и сравнить? Или просто использовать их.

ну что значит другой версии, это же библиотека встроенная, поэтому вся сложность вопроса как раз в том, чтобы это поправить и ничего не сломать

Если не используются компоненты, а только код из юнитов, то можно исходник модуля из другой версии (без ошибки) положить в папку к своему проекту, тогда будет использоваться он, а не штатный. Возможно придётся рядом положить некоторые зависимости. Не в 100% случаев работает, но попытка не пытка.

это представляется очень сложным, ведь там куча зависимостей и есть шанс попасть на скрытые баги, даже если формально все скомпилируется, поэтому и возник вопрос - может кто знает способ простой и проверенный

Ещё вариант я писал - сравнить версии, найти этот баг и исправить его.
